# How to give TableWidget's Cells different width

Tags: qt

I want to resize the TableWidget's cell to have different width instead of having the same width for all columns...
I've tried to use `ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(4, 10);` and give the fourth column a fixed width but this has done no effect as you can see in the photo below:

[image]

Comment: I've added this line of code ``` ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode (4, QHeaderView :: Fixed); ``` which worked well on all columns except the last one I don't know why...

Comment: Looks like you have enabled 'setStretchLastSection' - disable it.

Comment: Yes indeed that was it thank you